# Question about Pycron for windows

Tags: cron

Hi I test my web on my localhost(winxp+ie8+mysql5.0.51a+PHP 5.2.11+Apache 2.2.13). I want to add some cron job for my php files. I select Pycron. After configuration, I add some command in crontab.txt `* * * * * "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" http://localhost/test/index1.php`. It is success, it will open IEXPLORE.EXE and load index1.php for every minute. But it still open the IEXPLORE windows, not for close. how to set it automatic finish the php job, then close the IEXPLORE windows? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

how about using a command-line utility such as Curl or wget: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm? Or use Python with urllib/urllib2?

Comment: HI I just want to ask: how to do a cron job in windows, not a ftp tools.

Comment: use the 'at' utility. "help at" or "at /?" should explain the syntax.

Comment: @yuli the advantage of Curl or wget is that it automatically closes when the webpage has been loaded. Internet explorer is not meant to run at the commandline, it runs until a user closes the window. So you use cron the correct way, but should use wget instead of iexplore

Answer (score 2):

To fire a local PHP event through Pycron, you'll want to do something like this:

First create a new task. Then for the "Command" box in Pycron, enter the location of your PHP.exe file, eg "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php.exe"

for the "Parameters" box enter the location of the php file you want to run eg "C:\websites\mysite.com\cron.php"

You don't want to run any of that through Internet Explorer. Fire it directly at the PHP executable. Your server will thank you.